# Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help

**Error**

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

**my React Code**

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({appointment: nextProps.appointment })
        this.setState({responseObj: nextProps.responseObj })
     }


    render() {
        const appointment =   this.state.appointment;
        const responseObj = this.state.responseObj;
        const userId = this.props.userId;

        let content = null;
        let message = null;

         if(appointment === null ){
            content = 'loading ...';
        }

         if(appointment ===  false) 
            if(responseObj) {
                if(responseObj.data.errno === 1062){    
                    message = <div>appointment became unavailable.   </div>;
            }   
        }
        else {  
            content =  "no records ";
        }


            if(responseObj)
                if(responseObj.data.errno === 1062){    
                    message = "sorry, cannot reserve more than one appointment"   ;
                 }

        if(appointment )
        content = <SimpleMediaCard userId={userId} appointment={appointment} /> ;

        return( 
            <div>
                    {content}{ message}

            </div>
            );


    }
}


function mapStateToProps({appointment, responseObj }, ownProps){    

    return {appointment: appointment,
            responseObj: responseObj
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(SavedAppointments);
```

I removed unnecessary code, if you are interested in that, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

"setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied"

It seems to me that you should check if the below objects are created before using them, or otherwise placing a callback inside of `setState()`.

```
  const appointment =   this.state.appointment;
  const responseObj = this.state.responseObj;
  const userId = this.props.userId;
```

Comment: I updated code to be for example,   `this.setState({appointment: nextProps.appointment } , () => console.log(this.state))`
 but the warning is still there! and it prevents me from `message` variable assignment at my code.

Comment: you can go for promise or any asynchronous option like callback because as @Adam Patterson explained , it is not good to use setstate or immediately setted state variable in render.